# Why does my python program for calculating the greatest common divisior between two numbers sometimes giver the error "integer division by 0'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, greatest-common-divisor

```
def MDC(n,m):
    mdc = n
    while n % mdc != 0 or m % mdc != 0: 
        mdc = mdc - 1
    return mdc
```

Most of the time it works, but sometimes it gives the error "integer division or modulo by zero". What is going on?

Comment: For what inputs?

Comment: Why would you want to save that algorithm? That is almost the worst possible way to compute `gcd(m,n)` -- basically a brute-force search for it. This is exponentially slower than the Euclidean algorithm. Having said that, it should work for all inputs which are strictly positive integers.

Comment: Just use `math.gcd`.  It will be far faster, and it works properly for negative numbers (and it doesn't divide by zero).

Comment: I can't see how this would happen unless it's called with `n` being zero.

Comment: Apologies for the flip comment, what inputs give this result? As far as I can tell once `mdc = 1` the while loop should terminate and the function should return `1`. I mean, other than the obvious case of `n=0`.

Comment: Your code works when fed integers which are greater than 0 but fails when `n == 0`. But in that case, surely it is no mystery why the code is complaining about `%0`

Comment: One other case where this error can occur is if `m` is not an integer.

Comment: The main problem is the inefficiency of this approach. `math.gcd(10**100, 10**100 + 1)` will evaluate to `1` in a small fraction of a second. `MDC(10**100,10**100 + 1)` would take longer than the lifetime of the universe.

Answer (score -1):

If you still want to use that function even though it is exponentially slower than `math.gcd` ([Comment by John Coleman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68231432/why-does-my-python-program-for-calculating-the-greatest-common-divisior-between#comment120589943_68231432)) you could avoid the error by using `while (n % mdc != 0 or m % mdc != 0) and mdc != 0:` so the loop stops before reaching zero.

Comment: But how could `mdc` ever reach 0?  Surely `n % 1 != 0 or m % 1 != 0` will always be `False`.  The only way to skip `mcd` being 1 is if `n` wasn't an integer, but then `mcd` wouldn't reach 0 either.

Comment: @MarkRansom: If `m` is not an integer it can happen.

Comment: @FredLarson yes that's a good point.  I thought about non-integer `n` but not non-integer `m`.